# How to Taylor series expand at the prime at infinity

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Given a rational number, one can find a Taylor series expansion with respect to any $p$-adic valuation, as covered in Gouvea's introductory text on $p$-adic numbers. My question is how does one do this at the valuation at $\infty$?

Comment: Try the usual decimal expansion, for instance.  Or base 2. And so on. There is no canonical base to use.

Comment: @KConrad I was hoping to see something like the number of poles is equal to the number of zeros. So for instance the rational number 6 has a zero at the primes 2 and 3 and so it should have two poles at infinity.

Comment: You are looking for an analogue of the residue theorem, and that would be the product formula $\prod_v |x|_v = 1$ for $x \in \mathbf Q^\times$.

Comment: @KConrad Thank you. I am indeed familiar with that identity, but I was hoping to interpret each factor in the product formula you gave as the order of a pole of a certain Laurent series expansion at each local factor. Is this possible?

Comment: The problem is exactly that the place at infinity does not arise from a valuation.  There is an absolute value and a completion, but no additive valuation.